# why wouldn't this XPath example work?

Tags: xpath

I am trying to locate the first `<th>` element under a `<table>` element. The table element is tagged with a particular id, and is locatable when I only look as far as that tag.

But when I try to go a little further down and search using the XPath below, it returns a null element. The `'/th[0]'` is to say: return the first `<th>` element, under the element that is tagged with the particular id.

In the example, the id value is populated prior to the search:

```
"//*[@id='{0}']/th[0]"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XPath indexes are 1-based. Try: `//*[@id='{0}']/th[1]`

This trips me up all the time as well; too much time spent with 0-based indexing in C, C++, etc.

Comment: damn. that was a setup 10 years in the making. they got me. thanks